# Submit GET form in the url instead in the paramaters

Tags: javascript, html, forms, get

I have a get method form which goes to

```
mysite.com/?p=search&q=QUERY
```

but I want to let the form send me to

```
mysite.com/search/QUERY.
```

I have rewritten URL turned on in .htaccess.

Any help? How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the names of all these elements inside the form and take the values with js or jquery and set them to action attribute like

```
 $('#formid).attr('action','/url/search/'+query);
```

You would do this in onsubmit event and return true so that form gets submitted.

Comment: Wow. Yeah, that's a brilliant solution. You are a genius. Thanks man!